# Where can I get Sri Vidyaranya's Veda Bhashya?

Tags: vedas, advaita, resource, commentary

Where can I get [Sri Vidyaranya's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidyaranya) Veda Bhashya ?
Where will it be available?

Comment: Do you mean shri VidyarnavaTantra https://archive.org/details/SriVidyarnavaTantraUttarardhaPart1KapildevNarayana/page/n7/mode/2up

Comment: Bashya for Vedas by shri vidyaraya

Comment: They are all on archive.org. You just have to search.